# IIS rule rewrite for query string

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have a URL that looks like

```
https://thesite.com/m/?pageName=profileSettings#notifications
```

I need to rewrite it to

```
https://thesite.com/m/?pageName=notificationSettings
```

I'm trying something like

```
            <rule name="m_notifications" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^m/(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="pageName=profileSettings#notifications" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="pageName=notificationSettings" appendQueryString="False"/>
            </rule>
```

This isn't working, no errors, just not making any changes. What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do a rewrite based on the hash string. Browser doesn't transmit the part after hash to the server.

It's called [Fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) and is client side only. It's not possible in any language unless you are using some browser implementation (or software) which would send that part of URL to the server.

Comment: Well that answers why it wouldn't work. Thank you for answering. At least I know I'm not going mad.